# integrating SetTimeOut function after button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, settimeout

I have created a snippet of code that changes the state from display:block to display:none by using an onClick element. My goal is to delay the change in state, for a few seconds whilst an animation effect occurs.

This snippet of code below is what I am currently using to change the state of the element, but unsure on how to incorporate a delay.

Any advice or suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ant

```
function showDiv1(elem) {

  var divsToCheck = ["close","Holder"]; // Add to here to check more divs
  for (var i = 0; i < divsToCheck.length; i++) {
  if (divsToCheck[i] == elem) {
  document.getElementById(divsToCheck[i]).style.display = "block";
} else {
  document.getElementById(divsToCheck[i]).style.display = "none";
}
}
}
```

Comment: have you tried `setTimeout()`

Comment: The syntax is `setTimeout(function () { /* code here */  }, 5 * 1000);` (that's a five second delay)

Answer (score 0):

Put the code you want to be delayed inside an anonymous function, like so:

```
function showDiv1(elem) {

  var divsToCheck = ["close","Holder"]; // Add to here to check more divs
  for (var i = 0; i < divsToCheck.length; i++) {
    if (divsToCheck[i] == elem) {
      setTimeout(function() {
         document.getElementById(divsToCheck[i]).style.display = "block";
      }, 500);
    } else {
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById(divsToCheck[i]).style.display = "none";
      }, 500);
    }
  }
}
```

Here, 500 means delaying by 500 ms. You can change this to whatever amount of time (in milliseconds) that you need.

Answer (score 0):

You should call a function in your loop that takes care of the setTimeout and hiding/showing instead of calling the timeout function in a loop. (Won't work because i is no longer available). See here: https://jsbin.com/refodobaca/1/edit?html,css,js,output

```
function showDiv1(elem) {
  var divsToCheck = ["close","Holder"]; // Add to here to check more divs
  for (var i = 0; i < divsToCheck.length; i++) {
    if (divsToCheck[i] == elem) {
      showHideDiv(divsToCheck[i], true);
    } else {
      showHideDiv(divsToCheck[i], false);
    }
  }
}

function showHideDiv(elem, bShow) {

  var timeoutSeconds = 3;
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById(elem).style.display = (bShow ? "block" : "none");
  }, timeoutSeconds * 1000);

}
showDiv1('Holder');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear because the name of your function is `showDiv1` but you explain that you're trying to *hide* an element, so I've tried to answer in light of this and hopefully it will give you some ideas.

This code displays a couple of divs. If you click on them they turn red and, after a couple of seconds (to represent an animation), they are hidden.

`dummyAnim` returns a [`promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). After the animation has run its course (here represented by a two second delay) it is resolved. I've used [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) to pause code execution in an [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) function until the animation has resolved.

```js
// Grab the elements and add click handlers to them
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
divs.forEach(div => div.addEventListener('click', hideElement, false));

function dummyAnim() {

  // return a promise which resolves (an animation)
  // after two seconds
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), 2000);
  });
}

async function hideElement() {
  this.classList.add('red');
  await dummyAnim();
  this.classList.add('hidden');
}
```

```css
div { color: black; display: block }
.hidden { display: none }
.red { color: red }
```

```html
<div>close</div>
<div>holder</div>
```